# What is the name of this terminology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be the group generated by a set $X=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. Then each element can be (not necessarily uniquely) written as a product of the form $x_{j_1}^{e_1}\cdots x_{j_k}^{e_k}$, where each $x_{j_i}\in X$ and $e_i=\pm1$, $i=1,\cdots,k$. Among all possible such expressions, let $k$ be the number of terms in the "shortest" one. For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{x,y\mid x^7=y^4=1\}$, then the "$k$" for the element $x^5y^{-3}x^{-1}=x^{-1}x^{-1}yx^{-1}$ is $4$.

I am wondering if there is any standard terminology of the "$k$" defined above. Is it called the "weight" of an element?

Comment: Why is k=4 in your example? I think it should be k=3?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $k=4$ looks correct to me. What word of length $3$ represents that element? You might eb thinking of *syllable length*. If allow the $e_i$ to be arbitrary integers rather than $\pm 1$, then the least $k$ is often called the syllable length.

Comment: Oups, yes I forgot the exponents. Then it's the distance from the group element to $1_G$ in the Cayley graph w.r.t. $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common name is the *length* of the group element, which is defined to be the minimum length of words that define the element. Of course it depends on the choice of finite generating set, but changing $X$ will decrease or increase the length by at most a constant factor.