# "Length" of an element in a free group

Tags: group-theory, definition, free-groups

Is there any universally agreed definition of "length" (or "width", or whatever term) of an element in a free group $F_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$? Intuitively, I would like the length of $1$ to be $0$; the length of $x_2^{-3}x_1^4x_2x_1^2x_2$ to be $5$ and the length of $x_1^{-4}x_2x_1^2x_2$ to be $4$, etc.

Basically the idea is that the "length" of an element $W$ is the sum of the occurrences of each $x_i$ in the reduced word which is equivalent of $W$. Is there any clearer definition?

Comment: You are looking for the [word metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) on a group, I believe.

Comment: Not exactly... I think in $\mathbb{Z}$ my "length" of every element except $0$ is $1$; thus it is different from "word metric"?

Comment: What you are describing is often called *syllable length* rather than just length.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt! By the way, I think this question is a duplicate of [an earlier one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038355/what-is-the-name-of-this-terminology).

Comment: @DerekHolt, my earlier comment was incorrect. Now the O.P. sees clearly the difference between the length and the syllable length. Is there any reference for the term "syllable length"?

Comment: "Syllable length" is usually used in free products, but it applies here because a free group is a free product of the infinite cylic groups generated by the free generators. Try searching for "syllable length free product".

Answer (score 3):

This is the [word metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric#Definition), though  with respect to $S=\{\,x_i^k\mid 1\le i\le n, k\in\mathbb N\,\}$ instead of the generators only.

Comment: Thus my "length" of $W$ is actually the word metric between $w$ and the trivial element?

Comment: Why $k\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$?